# side navigation, links stuck to the right

Tags: html, css

I am pretty familiar with HTML but this is destroying me:

Pretty much I had a side navigation that is colored red.

the links are like this

```
________________________________
                          link  |
                          link  |
                          link  |
                          link  |
---------------------------------
```

When I want the links to be centered within that box

here is my css.

```
 #secNav{
 float:right;
 border:thin;
 background:#F23C3B;
 margin:20pz
 ;
 color:#FFFfff;

}

 #secNav a{
  text-decoration:none;
  color:#fff;
  list-style-type:none;


 }

 #secNav ul {
list-style-type: none;


 }
```

any help?

Comment: Update your post with your `html`

Comment: we need your HTML to make specific answer, but as I see the CSS, it is possible te problem comes form the `float:right;` property. Try replacing it by `text-align:center;`

Answer (score 0):

First is that how you have declared margin in your code? Are you trying to say:

```
margin: 20px;
```

Also then maybe wrap the un ordered list in a div that then sets the margins on either side to auto?

```
.ul{
margin-left:auto;
margin-right-auto;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's one example based on your question and CSS, <kbd>**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/mdesdev/jYe74/)**</kbd>

```
<nav id="secNav">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

---

```
#secNav {
  background: #f23c3b;
  float: right;
  width: 200px;
  margin: 20px;
  border: 1px thin;
}
#secNav ul {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
  text-align: center;
}
#secNav ul li {
  margin: 5px 0;
}
#secNav ul li a {
  text-decoration: none;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  color: #fff;
}
```